# How can I segment urine strip colors?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to extract a urinalysis strip colors to analyze them and need to segment color areas to have a robust solution.

[image: Aligned Urinalysis Strip]

Currently, I'm using a hardcoded distance from top approximation.
I already tried using adaptative thresholding and can't segment colors correctly without detecting background noise, joining multiple colors or not detecting some colors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are a bit over complicating this: your problem is in essence a 1D problem: you can look at the average color per row of your image, and this should give you a clean and more robust version to work on:

```
img = imread('http://i.imgur.com/mhGA3hp.jpg');
img = im2double(img);
avg = mean(img,2);
imshow(bsxfun(@times, avg, ones(1,50,3)));
```

Results with:
[image]

I believe you will find it easier to work with the 1D clean version of your image.